# Cross Building Bare-Metal Rust Program Aarch64

Tags: rust, linker, cross-compiling

I am working on transferring a bare-metal Raspberry Pi project from a Windows to Linux build system. The cross-compilation, which worked on Windows no longer works on Linux.

I have configured my `Cargo.toml` as follows:

```ini
[target.aarch64-unknown-none]
rustflags = ["-C", "link-arg=-Taarch64-raspi3.ld"]

[build]
target = "aarch64-unknown-none"
```

My build command is:
`cargo build -Zbuild-std=core,alloc --features=$(PLATFORM) --target=$(ARCH)`

I have layed out the linker script as follows:

```
ENTRY(_start)
SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x80000;
    .text : { KEEP( *(.text.boot)) *(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t*) }
    .rodata : { *(.rodata .rodata.* .gnu.linkonce.r*) }
    PROVIDE(_data = .);
    .data : { *(.data .data.* .gnu.linkonce.d*) }
    .bss (NOLOAD) : {
        . = ALIGN(16);
        bss_start = .;
        *(.bss .bss.*)
        *(COMMON)
        bss_end = .;
    }

    . = ALIGN(0x1000);

    TABLE_START = .;
    . += 0x1010;

    HEAP_START = .;
    . = . + HEAP_SIZE;

    . = ALIGN(16);
    MAILBOX_BUFFER_START = .;

   /DISCARD/ : { *(.comment) *(.gnu*) *(.note*) *(.eh_frame*) }
}
HEAP_SIZE = 1048576;
bss_size = (bss_end - bss_start)>>3;
```

However, when I run the build command, I get the following error:

`note: rust-lld: error: undefined symbol: bss_start`

And similar errors for the other symbols defined in the link script.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: if you provide a small reproducer it will be easier to investigate. can you provide a reproducer ?